# Is RSA key size the size of private key exponent?

Tags: rsa, key-size

I have implemented a key pair generation scheme for RSA algorithm. I have taken the length of private key exponent as RSA key size, but then I've got to know that RSA key size is the size of the modulus $n$. Is it wrong to take RSA key size as the size of the private key exponent?

To generate a private key of 1024 bits, I increase the size of private key exponent regardless the modulus $n$.

Comment: Note that I've seen many issues with regard to this, I've seen private key exponents that are two or even three **bytes** less than the size of the modulus (let alone bits) so please don't rely on the private exponent (or the secret S in ECC keys, as in your other question).

Answer (score 11):

**No**, the RSA key size is not *the size of the private key exponent*. It is customarily the number of bits in the *public modulus* (which is known as $N$). In other words, the key size is the integer $k$ such that $2^{k-1}\le N<2^k$.

In most implementations (and all implementations conforming to [PKCS#1](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/pkcs/files/h11300-wp-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard.pdf)), a private exponent $d$ has size in bits *at most* the key size $k$, and typically is few bits smaller. Notice that *the* private exponent is not uniquely defined.

The *smallest* private exponent is $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(N)$. It is always less than $\lambda(N)$, where $\lambda()$ is [Carmichael's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), with $\lambda(N)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ when $N=p\cdot q$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes. The smallest private exponent always has size in bits *strictly less than* the key size $k$, and typically is a few bits smaller.

Sometime, a private exponent is computed as $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(N)$, where $\varphi()$ is [Euler's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), with $\varphi(N)=(p-1)\cdot(q-1)$ when $N=p\cdot q$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes. That particular $d$ has size in bits *at most* the key size $k$, often is a few bits smaller, and often is a few bits larger than the smallest private exponent.

Yet other methods to define a private exponent give no maximum for $d$, and only require that $d\equiv e^{-1}\pmod{\lambda(N)}$ (which is the necessary and sufficient condition for $d$ to work), or $d\equiv e^{-1}\pmod{\varphi(N)}$.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to fgrieu's correct answer, I believe I want to emphasize something: **increasing the size of the private exponent beyond the size of the modulus does absolutely nothing to improve security**.  If you want to increase the strength of the RSA key, you must increase the size of the moduus.

As fgrieu mentioned, for any $e$ there is a minimal $d = e^{-1} \bmod \lambda(N)$; there is nothing preventing you from using a larger $d$; that means extra work on your part, but any operation you do is precisely equivalent to the smaller $d$, and hence the extra work buys you absolutely nothing.

In addition, we commonly use the Chinese Remainder Thereom to optimize the RSA private operations; when doing this, we actually compute:

$$C_p = (P \bmod p) ^ {d\  \bmod\  p-1} \bmod p$$

$$C_q = (P \bmod q) ^ {d\  \bmod\  q-1} \bmod q$$

(and then combine $C_p$ and $C_q$ to form the actual ciphertext)

We work with $d\  \bmod\  p-1$ and $d\  \bmod\  q-1$; it turns out these values are identical for any "equivalent" private exponent, and so a larger-than-necessary private exponent doesn't actually do anything (either good or bad)

Comment: does increasing size of the prime numbers p and q increase the size of the modulus n? how can I generate a RSA key with key size of 15 360?

Comment: @user2934766: since $n = p \times q$, then increasing $p$ and $q$ will, of course, increase $n$.  To pick an $n$ of 15360 bits, you need to select primes $p$ and $q$ of 7680 bits.  That said, if you think you need a public key system that difficult to solve, you probably should look at an Elliptic Curve system